# How to open logcat independent of Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Hi i'm pretty new to developing with Android and somewhat novice when it comes to Eclipse IDE. I'm wondering if it's possible to Launch logcat in a separate window and now nested inside eclipse?

Comment: Window -> show view -> logcat
then right click logcat -> detached

Answer (score 5):

You can launch just logcat window by using "ddms" command from the command promt(in windows). 
Usually ddms will be present in the path \sdk\tools

Answer (score 3):

They are stored as circular memory buffers on the device. It does not have any separated windows beside Eclipse but you can extract the log via command line:

```
android-sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat > c:\tmp\myfileandroid.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Android SDK setup locate the platform-tools folder and inside of there will be a binary called ADB. You can use that binary to launch in the CLI to have a separate logcat. For examle

C:\Users\Owner\Android SDK\platform-tools\adb logcat

For more information check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).